# Having troubles with installing ImageMagick on Maverick 10.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, imagemagick, rmagick

The last two days I am fighting with configuration of ImageMagick and rmagick gem. I found several topics on SO, but none of them helped me out with this issue.

Recently, I've tried update also `rvm`, but it didn't help me neither. When I run now `bundle update`, the output is:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
         /usr/local/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.8.6 Q8 is installed in /usr/local
         /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.8.8 Q16 is installed in /opt/ImageMagick
Using 6.8.6 Q8 from /usr/local.

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:565:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1044:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1043:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:194:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

How to proceed now - which ImageMagick to remove? Or, is there something else what am I overlooking?

Comment: How did you install ImageMagick in your machine? Also try it with `gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'` in your gemfile?

Comment: @Mandeep RMagick is just the ruby wrapper over ImageMagick which needs to be properly installed first.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I know! I asked how did he install not why did he :)

Answer (score 0):

The error hints at the problem:

> Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could
> cause problems at runtime.
> /usr/local/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.8.6 Q8 is installed in /usr/local
> /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.8.8 Q16 is installed in /opt/ImageMagick Using 6.8.6 Q8 from /usr/local.

And also:

> You have to install development tools first.

You can do this by entering the command `xcode-select --install` and clicking **Install**

This installs `gcc` among other things you need to compile ImageMagick and other sources.

Now remove one of your current installations of ImageMagick. Or remove both and install ImageMagick with homebrew:

```
brew update
brew install imagemagick
```

If that doesn't work here's some links I found that might help:

- ImageMagick Installer: http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/
- [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

Comment: Thank you Diego. At the moment, I struggle a bit on how to uninstall imagemagick. I know the one is installed through brew, but not sure about the second one.

Comment: The one that's installed with brew you can just `brew uninstall imagemagick`. It's safe however, to just delete the directory containing the program. The difference is brew will also delete any symlinks and other light weight things.